# RSelenium; Looping and downloading csv files

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to use RSelenium (with docker) to extract data from this website: https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx

```
#-- Load package
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

#-- Remote driver
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

#-- navigate to the website 
remDr$navigate("https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx/")

#-- confirm the website
remDr$getTitle()

#-- screenshot 
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

#-- Loading website's extra information
Sys.sleep(15)

#-- selecting filters: manipulate 
webElement <- remDr$findElement("class name", "switch")
webElement$clickElement()

webElement <- remDr$findElement("class name", "ng-input")
webElement$clickElement()
```

Until here, I'm able to select and click the dropdown menu but unable to select each of the items from the dropdown menu (I'm unable to find the correct xpath or id). I want to go through each of these items and also from the second dropdown menu, and then download their respective CSV file.

I want to perform everything using RSelenium. I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943923/looping-in-rselenium-and-scraping) but uses *rvest*. Is there an efficient way to extract all the CSV files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Spanish is a bit rusty but if I'm not mistaken you are trying to first toggle `los filtros de búsqueda por Sector e Institución` and then go through `sector`x`institución` combinations.

If you click on one of the combinations, say `Aportaciones de Seguridad Social`x`Fondo de la Vivienda del ISSSTE`, you can observe the following network request:

```
method GET
url "https://dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io/ms/InfoPadron/servidoresPublicosSector/19/HC6/1/100?query=nombres,primerApellido,segundoApellido,dependencia,tipoEntidad,nombrePuesto,sueldoBase,compensacionGarantizada"
Headers:
Host: dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101                 
Firefox/71.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx/
Origin: https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx
Connection: keep-alive
TE: Trailers
```

This response is a `JSON` containing the relevant data and we can make the very same request within `R` using `httr`:

```
# Make the request
headers <- c(
    "Host" = "dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io",
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv=71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0",
    "Accept" = "application/json",
    "Referer" = "https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx",
    "Origin" = "https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx",
    "Connection" = "keep-alive",
    "TE" = "Trailers"
)
url <- "https://dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io/ms/InfoPadron/servidoresPublicosSector/19/HC6/1/100?query=nombres,primerApellido,segundoApellido,dependencia,tipoEntidad,nombrePuesto,sueldoBase,compensacionGarantizada"

response <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(headers))
# Extract the data
data <- httr::content(response)
# Example, the first entry
data$listDtoServidorPublico[[1]]
# $nombres
# [1] "JOSE OSCAR"
# 
# $primerApellido
# [1] "ABURTO"
# 
# $segundoApellido
# [1] "LOPEZ"
# 
# $dependencia
# [1] "FONDO DE LA VIVIENDA DEL ISSSTE"
# 
# $tipoEntidad
# [1] "ORGANISMO DESCENTRALIZADO"
# 
# $nombrePuesto
# [1] "JEFE DE AREA PROF B EN PROC HIPOTEC FOVISSSTE"
# 
# $sueldoBase
# [1] 9432
# 
# $compensacionGarantizada
# [1] 2096
```

As you can see, this version is much simpler than using the heavy artillery that is Selenium+Docker.

Also, you can iterate over the `sector`x`institución` combinations. The key is probably the change the URL parameters to receive different combinations (i.e. the `?query=...` part of the URL. I have not investigated this myself but by checking the DOM and network when requesting other combinations you should be able to figure that out.

**Edit 1: Inspecting the Network**

In your Browser, toggle the *developer tools* and inside click on the tab *Network*. When you execute *Buscar* a new request should appear, namely one similar to the one above (depending on the chosen combination).

I've done this for another combination and observed the request url is

```
https://dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io/ms/InfoPadron/servidoresPublicosSector/25/C00/1/100?query=nombres,primerApellido,segundoApellido,dependencia,tipoEntidad,nombrePuesto,sueldoBase,compensacionGarantizada
```

Hence I was wrong about which part of the url you have to adapt: if you compare the two links here is how they differ

```
 url_1 = x + 19/HC6 + y
 url_2 = x + 25/C00 + y
 # where
 x = https://dgti-ejz-mspadronserpub.200.34.175.120.nip.io/ms/InfoPadron/servidoresPublicosSector/
 y = /100?query=nombres,primerApellido,segundoApellido,dependencia,tipoEntidad,nombrePuesto,sueldoBase,compensacionGarantizada
```

So it looks as if each `sector`x`institución` is coded as `VW/XYZ`. If you retrieve all of these, you can then iterate over the combinations.

Finally, if you inspect further the network chances are you'll find some request that contains a mapping of these encodings.

**Edit 2**

As suspected, when checking the network I encoutered the request labelled `sectores.json` with the following request url `https://nominatransparente.rhnet.gob.mx/assets/sectores.json`. This contains the mapping I was referring to for the `sector` part at least. Looking further might yield a similar one for `instutución`.

Possibly you have to toggle and click on a given `sector` to then see all the `institucón` options for the given `sector`. Then inside the DOM you'll see a similar mapping. I would suggest:

```
1. Get the sector mapping
2. Find out inside the network how the list of instituciónes is given back. Probably something like:
-> Request containing sector-ID in the URL -> return a JSON with all instituciónes
3. Once you figure out the logic behind it, use httr::GET to create a list of all sector x institución
4. Once you have this list, iterate over all combinations to get JSON data as above.
```

Comment: Hi @niko. Thanks for your answer. This seems to be a nice approach. I was wondering, this retrieves only the first page of the iteration - around 100 registries (e.g., `first sector` and `first institution`). May I ask, how did you get all the information from the `url` - ie., line 11 in your code?

Comment: Hey @niko. I went through your edits and it is super clear and helpful. At the moment, what I have done is just getting manually each sector plus institution, and retrieving the data. This is way more intuitive than what I was trying to do with RSelenium. Also, if I may ask, since it retrieves a JSON list, what would be the correct way to transform it as a data frame? I would like to continue all the retrieved data into just one single data frame.

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez `do.call(rbind, data$listDtoServidorPublico)` should do it for the above example